# iOS: universal link cannot pass the test on apple website

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, ios-universal-links, universal-link

I upload apple-app-site-association(AASA) file on my website and trying pass validation test on [Apple validator tool](https://search.developer.apple.com/appsearch-validation-tool/),

but It return me error:

> http://example.com is returning 503. Please check your url and try again.

```
{
  "applinks": {
    "apps": [],
    "details": [
      {
        "appID": "XXXXXXXXXX.com.XXXXXX.iosapp",
        "paths": [ "*" ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This file is uploaded on root folder and also .well-knows/ folders

like this -> https://www.example.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association

Answer (score 0):

`503` means that your web site was not available or server returned error to test tool at the time of check. It may be due to some servers or connection errors at the time of checking. But out of the blue, you also may want to check:

- does your website handles HTTPS ? AASA file needs to be accessible via HTTPS—without any redirects
- is your .well-known folder accessible for web server? To test enter whole link to it in browser
- check if you don't have any .htaccess or IP filtering rules that may prevent test tool access the file, even though you can access the file correctly from your location